# Selenium is not able to find elements

Tags: python, selenium, class, find, element

somehow my Selenium is not able to find elements on a website.
It is only possible to find the first `<div id="app" class="app-component">` every element below that won't be found.  [Here is a screenshot of the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLGxN.jpg).

e.g.
`driver.find_element_by_class_name("app-component")` works.
`driver.find_element_by_class_name("inner")` won't work.

Does it have something to do with `::before` inside the div?

Comment: I see a mention of `iframe` at the bottom of that screenshot... is the content in a `<frame>` tag?

Comment: @JohnGordon yes! It's in a `<iframe>` tag. I also included this in my code with `driver.switch_to.frame(0)` since it's the only frame on the site.

Comment: Try to switch to frame with ID: driver.switch_to.frame(frameID)